# Going to a wedding involving haram activities?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, wedding

> "…and he who refuses to accept an invitation to a marriage feast,
>   verily disobeys Allah and His Prophet”. (Ahmad & Abu Dawood)"

I've been invited to a wedding where I know there will be free mixing, men and women flirty, touching each other, kissing in public, partial nudity, dressed in tight clothing etc. I know they will have music and dancing. The music will have inappropriate words too.

Will I be disobeying Allah and his Prophet's command by not going to such a wedding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract from fatwa at islamqa:

> But the scholars have stipulated conditions for accepting an
>   invitation; if these conditions are not met then it is not obligatory
>   or mustahabb to accept the invitation, rather it may be haraam to
>   attend. These conditions were summed up by Shaykh Muhammad ibn
>   ‘Uthaymeen, who said:
>
> 1. There should be nothing objectionable (munkar) in the place where the party etc. is to be held. If there is something objectionable and
>      it is possible to remove it, then it is obligatory to attend for two
>      reasons: to accept the invitation and to change the objectionable
>      thing. If it is not possible to remove it then it is haraam to attend.

[Source](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/22006).

Comment: Your answer is essentially a fiqh answer. What about socially -- how should he respond to the inviter?

Comment: Yeah, I think the use of the [tag:practical-islam] is intentional here. How to practically handle the situation?

Comment: @oshirowanen what about the other side of the coin? What if I have a friend whom I want to invite to my wedding or someones's else and in my religion this is ok, I mean the music, dancing, etc? But at the same time I have no intention offending my friend and at the same time cherish him a lot and I wish he was there?

Comment: please mention the school of fitwa.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence) participating in such wedding is not permissible (Haram) and while not participating you should talk them in a polite manner and explain them it is sin and warn them and try to change their mind about such action ([Nahy min Munkar](http://www.al-islam.org/alpha.php?sid=713655420&cat=151&alpha_id=62&t=alpha)). But if you think there is no probability of accepting you then it is not obligatory to talk them in order to prevent them from sin.

---

**References:**

asked by online chat from [Official website of Grand Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/estefta/)